# Snackbar сверху

Tags: java, android

Пробую выводить Snackbar сверху следующим образом:

```
CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout=

(CoordinatorLayout)findViewById(R.id.coordinatorLayout);
Snackbar snackbar = Snackbar.make(coordinatorLayout, "Text", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG);
View view = snackbar.getView();
CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams params=(CoordinatorLayout.LayoutParams)view.getLayoutParams();
params.gravity = Gravity.TOP;
view.setLayoutParams(params);
snackbar.show();
```

Данный метод рабочий, так как при изменении параметра Gravity на BOTTOM, он выводится корректно. Но дело в том, что активити в котором я ео пытаюсь использовать, использует в манифесте родительскую активность(поэтому у меня выводится ещё дополнительно action bar)

Код в манифесте:

```
<activity
        android:name=".ForgotPasswordActivity"
        android:label="@string/forgot_password"
        android:parentActivityName=".LoginActivity">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".LoginActivity" />
    </activity>
```

Как возмонжо выводить snackbar ниже этого ActionBar'a?

Comment: `margin` добавить?..

Comment: @ЮрийСПб snackbaru? он же никак не отображается в моём xml файле. Или чему?

Comment: Да, ему. Точно так же как и Gravity - через LayoutParams

Comment: @ЮрийСПб так а как выбрать оптимальный margin? чтобы выводилось корректно? есть какая то величина у этого toolbar'a?

Comment: Да, есть. Аттрибут `actionBarSize`,  см последний метод в классе: https://github.com/mohaxspb/ScpFoundationRu/blob/develop/app/src/main/java/ru/dante/scpfoundation/util/DimensionUtils.java